# Setting up a secure SVN server on OSX Server edition

Tags: mac-osx-server, svn

I set up an svn server on my apple server running OSX server edition (leopard) following these instructions http://agileshrugged.com/blog/?p=14 and that was easy enough.

Unfortunately these instructions only describe how to set up an http based svn server and I would like to access my svn server using https.

I found these instructions http://www.sonzea.com/articles/subversion-trac.html online but when I got to step 7 it instructed me to add the following include: Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf but unfortunately OSX server does not have this .conf file.  This is not too surprsing because these instruction were about installing an svn server on OSX (not server edition).  I have not been able to find any instructions specifically about installing an svn server on OSX server edition and I am now somewhat stuck.

Can anyone either link me to some documentation specific to this situation or maybe should I refer to a different .conf instead of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that's just specifying an arbitrary path as an example. If you already have a signed certificate, the location they're stored doesn't matter as long as they're secured with proper perms, etc.

You will need to edit the httpd.conf file, set a permanent rewrite rule on port 80 to redirect to port 443. Now you must edit the ssl.conf file ( providing mod_ssl and openssl are installed ). Now you will be able to setup the virtual host for port 443 and specify the location of your private key, csr and .crt.

If you need more help, please email me: misconfiguration (AT) gmail (dot) com.